# Proper and flat morphism, geometric fibers nonempty, connected, and reduced implies isomorphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

So say I have $X$ over $S$ a proper and flat morphism. Here $S = \text{Spec}\,A$ and $A$ is a Noetherian ring. And further, assume that all the geometric fibers of $X$ over $A$ are nonempty, connected, and reduced.

**Question.** Does it follow that the natural map from $A$ to $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Please confer Theorem 12.11, Cohomology and Base Change, p. 290 of *Algebraic geometry* by Robin Hartshorne.  By part (a), to prove that the natural map of $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules $\mathcal{O}_S\to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)^\tilde{\ }$ is everywhere locally an isomorphism (hence an isomorphism, hence induces an isomorphism on global sections), it suffices to prove that for every point $y$ of $S$ the induced map $\kappa(y) \to H^0(X_y,\mathcal{O}_{X_y})$ is surjective.  This follows from the hypothesis that $X_y$ is proper, geometrically connected and reduced.